# Enum could not be found even though it's in the same namespace

Tags: c#, enums, blazor

I'm creating a simple Blazor RPS application for learning purposes, and I created an Enum for the results and options of the game, but whenever I try to call/use the enum, it says that it could not be found even though the same namespace is used

**Main file:**

```
@using RockPaperScissors.Client
@code
{
    List<Hand> OpponentHandOptions = new List<Hand>()
    {
        new Hand {Choice=Options.Rock, WinAgainst=Options.Scissors, LoseAgainst=Options.Paper, Image="Rock.png"},
        new Hand {Choice=Options.Paper, WinAgainst=Options.Rock, LoseAgainst=Options.Scissors, Image="Paper.png"},
        new Hand {Choice=Options.Scissors, WinAgainst=Options.Paper, LoseAgainst=Options.Rock, Image="Scissors.png"}
    };
}
```

**Enum file:**

```
namespace RockPaperScissors.Client
{
    public enum Options
    {
        Rock, Paper, Scissors
    }
}
```

The "Hand" class which is using the same namespace works fine and can be called

Comment: Based on the information provided i cannot determine what's wrong. I tried the same in a new project and the code is fine. Please edit the question with more information . Whats  Error Message for example ?

Comment: [Polite] Take the code you've provided, create a vanilla Blazor project and try it in that.  It works, so you aren't providing enough information to answer ther question.

Comment: You could check if your file is not being excluded in the .csproj.

Comment: maybe your file is not included. and check with the full name `RockPaperScissors.Client.Options` to see the result

Comment: I honestly don't know what the issue could be. Sorry for the inconvenience, the exact error is this: C:\Users\alhos\OneDrive\Desktop\Homework\Programming\RockPaperScissors\Client\Pages\Index.razor(104,26): error CS0103: The name 'Options' does not exist in the current context [C:\Users\alhos\OneDrive\Desktop\Homework\Programming\RockPaperScissors\Client\RockPaperScissors.Client.csproj]

Comment: So the Index File is in the folder Pages. Is the Option File in a folder or  just in the Client folder ?